# Loading internal text file as XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, my.resources

I'm writing a VB.NET app where I want to load an internal text file from Resource.

But the code shows **Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.**

The code is

```
'document.Load("C:\Users\Sou\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\info.xml")
document.Load(My.Resources.info)
'some processing job with XML node ...
```

So, how to load the resource file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim xdc As New XmlDocument
xdc.LoadXml(My.Resources.info)
MsgBox(xdc.OuterXml)
```