# Embedding and referencing XML file in VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, embedded-resource, xmldocument

In a VS2013 VB.NET WinForms project I need to include an XML file in the deployed application that will be read from and written to at run time.

I have the file as an embedded resource, and have "Copy Always" selected for output. The file name is "Settings.xml" and the resource name is Settings.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845457/loading-internal-text-file-as-xml) example I did the following to reference it in my code:

```
Private xmlFile as XmlDocument ' In the general declaration area, before the Load event
xmlFile.LoadXml(My.Resources.Settings) ' In the Load event, in a Try/Catch
```

But I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the second line.

In the code I plan on accessing the xml with something like this:

```
Dim xmlDoc as New XmlDocument
xmlDoc = xmlFile
```

I'm not sure yet how to save any changes I make, as initial attempts of  something like `xmlDoc.Save(xmlFile)` didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: you do know you loading it is a one time proposition.  you cannot save back to compiled resources at which point you might as well create the file elsewhere to begin with

Comment: I am curious why `My.Settings` is not enough?  If you have good reason to reinvent the wheel, why treat it as an XML file versus `XMLSerialization`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use the constructor for `xmlFile`:

```
Private xmlFile As New XmlDocument
```

Then, all you need to do is use the resource name, i.e. "Settings.xml" if the resource is embedded:

```
xmlFile.LoadXml("Settings.xml")
```

You shouldn't even need to set the resource as "CopyAlways".

Comment: Thanks, roryap, but I tried that and got the same error (Object reference...).

Comment: @marky -- Please note what I said about the constructor.

Comment: Okay, I saw that you had "New" in there, so I added that, but now I'm getting this error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." If that's referring to the first line of my xml file, it starts out with a standard doctype declaration: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: @marky -- That's a different question -- outside the scope of this one.  You either need to accept this answer or not.  Ask a new question for the rest.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You provide a suggested solution that causes an error and you're telling me that can only be resolved by posting another question?

Comment: @mark -- You're piggy backing a subsequent issue on your first issue.  We could be here all day going from one issue to the next until you get your software working.  That's not how SO works.  You have a very specific problem outlined in your question.  I've addressed that problem in my answer.  Either it resolved your *specific* problem, or it didn't.  Anything that happens AFTER that initial problem is resolved is outside the scope of the question.